# ListView equivalent using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, listview

I am transitioning a WPF application to the Web using ASP.Net MVC and jQuery. In my WPF application I have a ListView containing thumbnails and captions that looks like this:

[image]

I need to display something similar in my web-based application.

Requirements:

- User must be able to select items in the list (multiple selection would be useful).
- The number of items in this ListView can number in the thousands so lazy loading of the thumbnail images is desirable.
- The list of images *can* be known at page-load time, but if the list could be gotten via an AJAX call that would be even better, as I would also like to provide filter/search functionality.
- Resizing support is desirable as I'd also like to have hideable side-panels displaying information for the selected image(s).

What is the best way to achieve something like this using html and jQuery? Is there a plugin that does something like this?